# laravel eloquent joins in custom query builder?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to use joins in a custom query builder:

```
    class UserBuilder extends Builder
    {
        public function withActiveCompany(): self
        {
            return $this->join('companies', 'users.company_id', 'companies.id')
                    ->where('companies.is_active', true);
        }
}
```

However this would cause problems if multiple methods in the builder join the same table since mysql will complain: Not unique table/alias: 'companies'

Is there some way to tell eloquent to just get rid of the duplicate joins if they are identical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to check your query before joining tables using the **getQuery()** method of the **Builder** class.

Not tested, but this can help you achieving what you want.

```
 $query = $this->getQuery();

 $joins = collect($query->joins);

 $hasJoinedCompanies = $joins->contains(function ($join) {
     return $join->table === 'companies';
 });

 if (!$hasJoinedCompanies) {
     $query->join('companies', 'users.company_id', 'companies.id');
 }

 $query->where('companies.is_active', true);

 return $this;
```